# Not able to access file on Local machine using Android even if the file is exist into the machine

Tags: java, android, file, ioexception

I am trying to read file from the Local storage inside the Project of an Android.
However I am still having error like file not found exception. I had print the path of the file and I have checked with the browser file is there on the same path. but I am having still exception.

```java
    try {
                    File file = new File("D:\\Android SDK\\AndroidWorkspace\\Assignment4Test\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\studentnameid.txt");

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("File Is there ");

                    } else {
                        //It always executes the else blog.
                        file.createNewFile();
                        System.out.println(" file is not there so its creating Created File");

                    }
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());


                    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

`D:\\Android SDK\\AndroidWorkspace\\Assignment4Test\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\studentnameid.txt` is a path to a file on a Windows PC. Android is not Windows. You do not use Windows filesystem paths to refer to anything on Android.

My guess, based on that path, is that you have a file in your project in `assets/`. If so, use `AssetManager` (via `getAssets()` on a `Context`) and its `open()` method to access your asset. That will give you an `InputStream` to read from, directly or via an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: I have already tried this but its not working for me can you please give me link for an example so i can check

Comment: @Krishna: [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.4) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) has a PDF file in `assets/`. [This Java class](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/blob/v0.4/PdfProvider/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/pdfprovider/MainMotor.java) reads in the asset and copies it to a file on internal storage. Note that I am using `Application` here, but any `Context` will work.

Comment: I dont find the reference code there. It would be really nice if you can give link to sample example..

Comment: v.getRootView().getContext().getResources().getAssets().open("assets/studentnameid.txt") I have tried this

Comment: @Krishna: "It would be really nice if you can give link to sample example" -- I did. "I have tried this" -- replace `"assets/studentnameid.txt"` with `"studentnameid.txt". The path you provide to open is the relative path *inside* of `assets/` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify this you have to use a localhost WAMP (for Windows ) or MAMP(for Mac), then store your file in the (www) folder, Go to android studio and set the link of your file like ( http://192.168.1.100/studentnameid.txt)

> the 192.168.1.100 is your local IP address.

Not: you must change your IP address by the domaine name when you publish your app in Google play or other platforms